# chrome net::ERR_ABORTED on one from several .css file

Tags: php, css, google-chrome, xampp

today I started some boilerplate project. I am using gulp to output minified css from SASS. I have two .css files - normalize.css and main.css. Both of them are minified from the same directory. When I am starting localhost with XAMPP I open index.php it could not load main.css but normalize.css is loaded. I get the following in console:

[image]

Also when I go to see files that are in localhost directory I see that main.css is there, but when I click on it it says that it could not found this file - error 404 and in url bar I see that it added "/" at the end of main.css - strange behaviour:

[image]

However when I open this index.php in Firefox everything is fine and both styles are loaded and displayed correctly. Here is index.php code if needed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title>Title of site</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./dist/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./dist/css/main.css">

    <!-- FavIcon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="//" sizes="32x32">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Local -->
    <!-- <script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script> -->

  </head>
  <body>

      <h1>Hello wosfsdfsdfrld!</h1>
      <p>scss and sass</p>

      <p><?php echo('THIS IS HEADERsfsfsdf'); ?></p>

      <img src="./img/testimg.png">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So it seems that it is somehow related to Chrome Browser, what could be an issue? Maybe some XAMPP config? But I have never touched it

Answer (score 1):

The problem was name of folder containing project "siteStarter-php" caused some conflicts - changed it to "siteStarterPhp" and everything is working

Comment: What about the project name caused conflicts, and why do you believe Chrome did not like it (while Firefox did)?

Comment: Could you please comment on that?